# unable to use @WebscoketGateway decorator in nest js

Tags: nestjs

unable to use @WebscoketGateway decorator in nest jsgetting this errorTypeError: this.metadataScanner.getAllMethodNames is not a function
at GatewayMetadataExplorer.explore

i think there is some version issue

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens if `@nestjs/common`, `@nestjs/core`, `@nestjs/platform-express|fastify|ws|socket.io` and `@nestjs/websockets` are not all on the same version. They must be the same major, minor, and patch